# TypeError: xxx.contains is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to create a conditional rendering in Gatsby with React JSX. I provided a few parameters for the function as follows:

```
const Button = (href, text, btnType, ...props) => {
    if (href.contains("http")) {
        return (
            <a href={href} {...props}>
                <button className={btnType}>
                    <span>{text}</span>
                </button>
            </a>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <Link to={href} {...props}>
                <button className={btnType}>
                    <span>{text}</span>
                </button>
            </Link>
        )
    }
}
```

as you can see, the few parameters for the function are href, text and btnType.

On the pages where I implement the Button component, it is as follows:

```
<Button
    btnType="btn-cta"
    text="External Link"
    href="https://google.com">
</Button>
<Button
    btnType="btn-nav"
    text="Internal Link"
    href="/">
</Button>
```

But it provided `TypeError: href.contains is not a function` error.

What can I do to fix this? I'm very new to JavaScript and React so any elaborate answers would be appreciated so I can fully understand what went wrong with my code.

Comment: use `href.includes` instead. If you want to learn, I recommend reading MDN from time to time. Here is a list of String methods, which shows you are looking for 'includes': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2 If you want to support Internet Explorer, you can use .indexOf instead, but don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`href` is a prop to your component. Not a parameter. You need to use

```
const Button = ({ href, text, btnType, ...props }) => {...
```

which means you want to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Basic_assignment) the first parameter to your function, and get `href`, `text`, `btnType` from the props object and then take the *rest* of the props into `...props`.

As per your current code, the `href` parameter contains *all* the props to your component, not just the `href` prop. Put a breakpoint in your `Button` function and you'll see the `href` is an object.

Also, as [@George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5674976/george) mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256469/typeerror-xxx-contains-is-not-a-function-in-react/58256500#comment102881952_58256469), you should use `includes` as `contains` is deprecated and probably doesn't exist on String's prototype in modern browsers.

Comment: I made the changes as you've stated and it shows a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined` error. Do you have to make the changes in ```<Button
    btnType="btn-cta"
    text="External Link"
    href="https://google.com">
</Button>
<Button
    btnType="btn-nav"
    text="Internal Link"
    href="/">
</Button>
``` as well?

Comment: No. No changes in the consumption. Are you sure these are the only 2 buttons in your App?

Comment: @aahlfeeyann were you able to find the problem? If not, try to share a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) where there is a minimal app to reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes i'm able to solve the problem. it seems to just be a cache issue i think? i deleted the original button.js file and recreated a new buttonS.js file with an extra s at the back and relinked it, it do work. not sure what was the problem previously. Thanks for your help!